# Use of unresolved identifier 'indexPath' in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hello I'm creating variable URL and I'm getting error in this line.

Here's my full code.

"Use of unresolved identifier 'indexPath' in Swift"

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class DetailViewController: UIViewController{

    var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!
    var color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var name = NSString()
    var arrayOfPrograms: NSArray = []

    var url = NSString()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
            [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)!,
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = color
        self.navigationItem.title = "TV JOJ"

        var url = NSURL(string: (self.arrayOfPrograms.objectAtIndex(indexPath).Program).url)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

        moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        moviePlayer.view.sizeToFit()
        self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
        moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    }

}
```

I'm sorry I'm Beginner..

Cells

```
var arrayOfPrograms: NSArray = []
arrayOfPrograms = [Program(name: "Markíza", url: "http://1.com")]
```

This is how I'm trying to pass data through segue

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow() as NSIndexPath!
        var destinationViewController: DetailViewController
        (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).url = (self.arrayOfPrograms.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as Program).url
```

I want that url will open a different video for each named cell. arraysOfPrograms is cells.

Comment: You will have to provide more scope context. Try posting the full definition of the function that the one line you posted is contained within.

Comment: We can't read your mind. Show us more code.

Comment: What do you expect `indexPath` to be there? Currently the variable is not defined anywhere, that's your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Mundi's answer - These Lines -

```
    var url = NSURL(string:(self.arrayOfPrograms.objectAtIndex(indexPath).Program).url)
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
```

Can be written like this, which is a bit more clear -

```
    var url = self.arrayOfPrograms.objectAtIndex(indexPath).Program.url;
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url);
```

The main issue is that the variable "indexPath" doesn't exist anywhere in your program so your not telling your program which index to get out of the arrayOfPrograms array.

Like Mudi said, even if "indexPath" was defined NSIndexPath isn't the type you would want to pass in there anyways, you'd want to pass in that indexPath's row. So it would look like this

```
    // this indexPath probably isn't what you want. Its just an example to illustrate my point.
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)

    // getting the row (1) from the variable indexPath
    var url = self.arrayOfPrograms.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).Program.url
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
```

What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to to loop through the arrayOfPrograms and create a movie player for each item thats in that array? Or should this be in a table view and when a user clicks on a specific row. Answering those particular questions will help you figure out where "indexPath" is supposed to come from.

Comment: I want that url will open a different video for each named cell. arraysOfPrograms is cells. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `indexPath` is not properly defined. Also, to access a member of an array you need an index, not an index path.

Note that you have to do two things to repair this:

1. Properly define or get a reference to a `NSIndexPath`
2. in `objectAtIndex` use `indexPath.row` (or `indexPath.item`, if it is a collection view). But in Swift (and modern Objective-C) we would prefer to write

```
arrayOfPrograms[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: No you didn't. According to your code you did not define `indexPath`